# FFmpeg split videos into smaller chunks of 15 second each with a stride of 10 seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I want to split a 1 hour video into chunks of 15 seconds each. But after every 15 seconds I want to skip 10 seconds. For eg:- I want a clip from first 0-15 seconds save it, then skip 10 seconds, the second clip should be from 25-40 th second from the original video. Does someone know how to implement this using FFmpeg ?

ffmpeg -I Vid.mp4 -f segment -segment_atclocktime 1 -segment_clocktime_offset 00:00:10  -segment_time 00:00:15 -reset_timestamps 1 output_%03d.asf

This command is not working as expected. I don't want to implement this in a for loop, but in a single pass

Comment: use the `-segment_times 15,25,40` option and delete the unwanted 15-25 clip.

Comment: Is there some way we can do this without the deleting clips ? I will be working with more than 1000 videos, so deleting them all will be difficult. Does ffmpeg has some inbuilt command to do this easily ?

Comment: File management isn't what ffmpeg is. It is an open-source program though, so i suppose you can create your own muxer to do what you want to do...

Comment: what I meant is does ffmpeg has a single command line argument similar to "-f segment -segment_time 15" which cuts down a video into smaller chunks of 15 seconds, but I want each 15 seconds chunks separated by 10 seconds, for example by adding an extra paramter "-offset  10" seconds. I thought "-segment_clocktime_offset " command could do that.